# Charged ions distribution in a cylindrical container

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, ions

> In a cylindrical container of radius $R$ and height $h\ll R$, with vertical axis, is contained an ionized gas (total sum of the charges $=0$). The particles with positive charge $q>0$ have mass $M$ and the ones with charge $-q$ have mass $m<M$. The temperature is constant and uniform, and ions can't bond between each other. Gravity is not ignored. The particles are treated like points.
>
> a) Qualitatively, what's the distribution of those particles?
>
> b) Calculate the electric field inside the cylinder.

The solution I looked up gives a very (in my opinion) non-rigorous answer that I'm not happy with. It states that since kinetic energy is the same between all particles, the velocity of the negative ions is greater than the positive's one (and this makes sense). From that, since pressure must be uniform there cannot be layers with different density (for point a) and that a non-zero electric field would imply an attraction between the ions and thus it must be 0 (point b).

I do not understand well those conclusions, especially the first one. Why can't there be two different densities? If there was an electric field inside the container, obviously the ions would be attracted, but for the bottom ones there would be gravity and for the top ones maybe a too steep pressure or density gradient. I'm maybe lacking some fundamental concepts of thermodynamics (which is likely, I suck at TD) or maybe some steps are just not clear enough for me.

If someone could rewrite better the answer I quoted or, even better, come up with a different one it would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

P.S. The answer I'm quoting is not official and can therefore contain some mistakes. Since it's not originally written in English and is purely conceptual, some aspects of the answer may not be completely loyal to the original construction. Feel free to ask for as many clarifications as needed.

Comment: There would certainly be a density gradient from gravity as you suggest, but it could be that the author of the question ignores it because $h\ll R$ and the cylinder is arranged parallel to the ambient gravitational field.  How much rigor are you looking for in the answer?

Comment: @TLDR it is probably as you are saying. The approximation given by the problem is in fact pretty meaningless if not used to ignore the density gradient. But I still don't properly understand the reasoning behind since a lot of the conceptual steps are missing. I'm looking for an answer that can maybe be simple but backs up the majority of the steps taken. Some formulae may be greatly beneficial in visualizing the process. To sum it up, just a normal answer to both the point as if there wasn't one yet. People here always made everything crystal clear